# How to center the text in a UITextField although there exists a leftView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I'd like to center (horizontally align) the text in a text field (including the placeholder text) although there is a leftView added to the `UITextField`.

When adding a left view to a `UITextField`, the text is not centered anymore.

How can I fix this? I user should not be able to override the left view when entering text in the TextField.

This is an example:

[image]

I thought about adding the same view as the right view and set its alpha value to zero, but I don't think that would be an elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to create it custom like this without `leftView`

```
UIView
       - 0 - UIImageView - 10 - UITexfield - 10
       - 0 -  separator (UIView) - height(1)- 0
```

Then copy paste that view for password

Comment: Looks good, thanks. So you would create a view with a height of 1 as separator? At the moment I am using the `UITextField's` shadow as the separator.